# pydantic validation PyCharm: This decorator will not receive a callable it may expect; the built-in decorator returns a special object

Tags: python, pycharm, decorator

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Request(BaseModel):
    num: int

    @validator("num")
    @classmethod
    def validate_num(cls, num: int) -> int:
        return num
```

PyCharm gives the warning "This decorator will not receive a callable it may expect; the built-in decorator returns a special object" for the above code. I don't think the warning is clear so I'd appreciate some help.

When I change the above code to this:

```
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError

from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from pydantic.error_wrappers import ErrorWrapper


class Request(BaseModel):
    num: int

    @classmethod
    @validator("num")
    def validate_num(cls, num: int) -> int:
        if num < 0:
            raise RequestValidationError([ErrorWrapper(ValueError("error"), ())])
        return num


request = Request(num=-2)
```

The warning goes away, but the code executes without any problem when it's not supposed to, meaning that the validation has been ignored for some reason.

Comment: It's just suggesting that you put `@classmethod` above the other decorator, since the return value of `classmethod()` is not a normal function, and may not work with a typical decorator that is expecting a function.

Comment: @jasonharper hmm. I put it above the other decorator, but now the validation function is ignored. Please check my new edit.

Comment: @snakecharmerb a quote from the doc [here](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/):

"validators are "class methods", so the first argument value they receive is the  UserModel class, not an instance of UserModel"

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/41ac98aee41aeb6e6592091055a61406036425d7/pydantic/decorators.py#L20) on github, you'll see that the `validator` decorator already returns a `classmethod`.

```py
def validator(
    *fields: str,
    mode: Literal['before', 'after', 'wrap', 'plain'] = 'after',
    check_fields: bool | None = None,
    sub_path: tuple[str | int, ...] | None = None,
    allow_reuse: bool = False,
) -> Callable[[Callable[..., Any]], classmethod[Any]]:
```

Simply remove your `@classmethod` decorator!

Comment: Removing the `@classmethod` decorator will yield a warning (in PyCharm) saying that usually the first parameter of a method should be self. Adding the `@classmethod` on top of the other decorator seemingly makes PyCharm happy, but breaks the code as it already returns a classmethod. Only way I found to fix this is to install the `pydantic` plugin in PyCharm.

Comment: @Daniel, pydantic plugin won't help

Comment: @Oleg The `pydantic` plugin does help if you don't use the `@classmethod` in addition to `@field_validator`. As @Stateless mentioned, the validator itself returns a `classmethod`, so it's not necessary to decorate it twice.

Answer (score 2):

It's false positive hint in PyCharm

Related issue:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34368/False-warning-This-decorator-will-not-receive-a-callable-it-may-expect-when-classmethod-is-not-the-last-applied